# The empty string '' is not a valid local name. - Xamarin Forms PCL SOAP request call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, soap, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make a SOAP request and I am catching an Exception, you can see it below. (I am not consuming WCF)

Maybe someone had similar issues and knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

{System.ArgumentException: The empty string '' is not a valid local name.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)
  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) :end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.EndProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0001f] in <475dec2c1fe44b95bbfbd21b550b63f8>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+ChannelBase`1[TChannel,T].EndInvoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00045] in <475dec2c1fe44b95bbfbd21b550b63f8>:0 
  at App3.AscoTms.imcwpPortTypeClient+imcwpPortTypeClientChannel.EndLogin (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00008] in C:\Users\georgij.nebudrov\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\Connected Services\AscoTms\Reference.cs:3833 
  at App3.AscoTms.imcwpPortTypeClient.App3.AscoTms.imcwpPortType.EndLogin (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in C:\Users\georgij.nebudrov\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\Connected Services\AscoTms\Reference.cs:3088 
  at App3.AscoTms.imcwpPortTypeClient.EndLogin (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in C:\Users\georgij.nebudrov\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\Connected Services\AscoTms\Reference.cs:3093 
  at App3.AscoTms.imcwpPortTypeClient.OnEndLogin (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in C:\Users\georgij.nebudrov\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\Connected Services\AscoTms\Reference.cs:3103 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+<>c__DisplayClass39_0[TChannel].<InvokeAsync>b__0 (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00006] in <475dec2c1fe44b95bbfbd21b550b63f8>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at App3.MainPage+d__2.MoveNext () [0x00081] in C:\Users\georgij.nebudrov\source\repos\App3\App3\App3\MainPage.xaml.cs:47 }